Docker Compose Up is not working due to Docker Image and Manifest versions
I recently started working on a project for a company, and their project is dockerized. Problem is when I run docker compose up to set up the container for local work, I get this error:
Error response from daemon: [DEPRECATION NOTICE] Docker Image Format v1 and Docker Image manifest version 2,schema 1 support is disabled by default and will be removed in an upcoming release. Suggest the author of docker.io/library/mysql:5.5.42 to upgrade the image to the OCI Format or Docker Image manifest v2, schema 2. More information at https://docs.docker.com/go/deprecated-image-specs/   

Now updating the Image Format and manifest is not an option here. I am on windows with wsl 2 as well. Running it on both Windows CMD or WSL2 yields the same error. Is there a workaround for this? Im on Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230, with Docker Compose version v2.29.7-desktop.1. I am new to docker, so I am stumped.
Edit: 
So I tried running docker compose via the docker installation available from the snap store on wsl2 (its in Ubuntu), and running docker compose worked there, however, it didn't expose the ports and API endpoints of the project, so I am still stuck. But this raises the question as to why the docker installed from the snap store was functional, but docker-desktop for windows is not.
